# Oracle SQL Group Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I am attempting to summarize a employee table where multiple records exist while an employee is in one team. I have attempted to group by, Min/Max Over Partition By and Lead/Lag the team name but every result ends in an agent that has moved from one team and then at a later date back to the original team group as one occurrence even though I am sorting by the dates.

Example Database:

```
Employee Name | Employee ID | Team Leader | Location | Start Date | End Date

John Smith    | 123123      | Team A      | Site A   | 01/JAN/19  | 02/JAN/19

John Smith    | 123123      | Team A      | Site A   | 02/JAN/19  | 03/JAN/19

John Smith    | 123123      | Team B      | Site A   | 03/JAN/19  | 04/JAN/19

John Smith    | 123123      | Team A      | Site A   | 04/JAN/19  | 05/JAN/19

John Smith    | 123123      | Team B      | Site A   | 05/JAN/19  | 06/JAN/19
```

When I run an example query:

```
SELECT
Employee Name
,Employee ID
,Team Leader
,Location
,MIN(Start Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Team Leader ORDER BY Employee ID, Start Date) AS Starting Date
,MAX(End Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Team Leader ORDER BY Employee ID, End Date) AS End Date
FROM TABLE 1
```

The Results are as follows:

```
Employee Name | Employee ID | Team Leader | Location | Start Date | End Date

John Smith    | 123123      | Team A      | Site A   | 01/JAN/19  | 05/JAN/19

John Smith    | 123123      | Team B      | Site A   | 03/JAN/19  | 06/JAN/19
```

Can any assist with achieving the desired results:

```
Employee Name | Employee ID | Team Leader | Location | Start Date | End Date

John Smith    | 123123      | Team A      | Site A   | 01/JAN/19  | 03/JAN/19

John Smith    | 123123      | Team B      | Site A   | 03/JAN/19  | 04/JAN/19

John Smith    | 123123      | Team A      | Site A   | 04/JAN/19  | 05/JAN/19

John Smith    | 123123      | Team B      | Site A   | 05/JAN/19  | 06/JAN/19
```

Comment: Look for gaps and islands. A lot of post could be found

Comment: It's a duplicate question, though I have problems to find answer which best suits here. Solution is something like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=66dac9b18570d0b19c9647f9fed26848).

Comment: @PonderStibbons I tested a similar logic from the link you provided, and it appears to work. I'll verify when I add more employee's into the query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a form of gaps-and-islands where records are linked by date ranges.

Here is one method that uses `left join` to find where islands begin, then a cumulative sum for identifying the groups and aggregation:

```
select employeename, employeeid, teamleader, location,
       min(startdate), max(enddate)
from (select t1.*,
             sum(case when tprev.employeeid is null  -- new group
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) over (partition by employeeid, teamleader, location
                            order by startdate
                           ) as grouping
      from table1 t1 left join
           table1 tprev
           on t1.startdate = tprev.enddate and
              t1.employeeid = tprev.employeeid and
              t1.teamleader = tprev.teamleader and
              t1.location = tprev.location
     ) t
group by employeeid, teamleader, location, grouping
order by employeeid, min(startdate);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems to solve my problem and groups the agent's correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option:

- `test` CTE represents your data (simplified a little bit)
- *useful* code is from line #8 onwards

---

```
SQL> with test (ename, team, start_date, end_date) as
  2    (select 'John', 'A', date '2019-01-01', date '2019-01-02' from dual union all
  3     select 'John', 'A', date '2019-01-02', date '2019-01-03' from dual union all
  4     select 'John', 'B', date '2019-01-03', date '2019-01-04' from dual union all
  5     select 'John', 'A', date '2019-01-04', date '2019-01-05' from dual union all
  6     select 'John', 'B', date '2019-01-05', date '2019-01-06' from dual
  7    ),
  8  temp as
  9    (select ename, team, start_date, end_date,
 10       row_number() over (order by start_date) rn,
 11       row_number() over (partition by ename, team order by start_date) rna
 12     from test
 13    )
 14  select ename, team, min(start_date) start_date, max(end_date) end_date
 15  from temp
 16  group by ename, team, (rn - rna)
 17  order by 3;

ENAM T START_DATE  END_DATE
---- - ----------- -----------
John A 01/jan/2019 03/jan/2019
John B 03/jan/2019 04/jan/2019
John A 04/jan/2019 05/jan/2019
John B 05/jan/2019 06/jan/2019

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have version 12c or later, row pattern matching is a good alternative solution. Unlike the "gaps and islands" solutions, I take care of overlaps too. The WITH clause contains test data, the solution starts afterwards.

```
with test (ename, team, start_date, end_date) as
 (select 'John', 'A', date '2019-01-01', date '2019-01-02' from dual union all
  select 'John', 'A', date '2019-01-02', date '2019-01-03' from dual union all
  select 'John', 'B', date '2019-01-03', date '2019-01-04' from dual union all
  select 'John', 'A', date '2019-01-04', date '2019-01-05' from dual union all
  select 'John', 'B', date '2019-01-05', date '2019-01-06' from dual
 )
select * from test
match_recognize(
  partition by ename, team order by start_date
  measures first(start_date) start_date, last(end_date) end_date
  pattern(a b*)
  define b as start_date <= a.end_date
)
order by ename, start_date;

ENAM T START_DATE       END_DATE        
---- - ---------------- ----------------
John A 2019-01-01 00:00 2019-01-03 00:00
John B 2019-01-03 00:00 2019-01-04 00:00
John A 2019-01-04 00:00 2019-01-05 00:00
John B 2019-01-05 00:00 2019-01-06 00:00
```